# How to change color of menu item icon in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following menu item:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/icon_two"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_secure"
        android:title="Secure Function"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
```

but it's on black background and the ic_secure icon is black-ish and you can't really see it. I would like to make it white. Is that possible ? Or do I have to use another icon.. ?

Comment: surely there is a way to change the picture color , but i suggest you to change it yourself for this time ... here is a website that may helps http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C60

Comment: I have this same problem. It looks like the android drawables are by default slightly transparent so they match whatever color action bar you have. I use a green action bar, and my icons have a green tint to them. It's not bad, but I'd love to see if there's a solution to this.